# Create a blog through the Rest API

Tags: wordpress, rest

I need to migrate content from Ning to WordPress 4.1 and I'm planning to use Rest Api(json-api plugin) for that purpose. But i get confused a little bit, there is no methods for creating blogs, events etc.
Is it possible to create blog using Rest Api?

Comment: please describe the problem little bit more, what is the current version of wordpress, what is the content format as you have stated  not Wordpress source you need to migrate?

Comment: Are you wanting to create a blog or a blog post? There is a big difference.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `JSON-API` WordPress plugin for creating the restful web-services that can be used for fetching the data from Wordpress.

And the plugin will provide the webservice url something like that :

`www.mysite.com/api/servicename`

Plugin link : https://wordpress.org/plugins/json-api/

Hope it helps you some extent.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I know that json-api will help me, but i'm not sure that it has all methods that i need for.

Comment: If all the methods provided will not fulfill your requirements then you can easily create your new methods/services. `json-api` plugin provides flexibility to create new custom methods too..

Comment: Sounds like a good solution for a php developer, but not for .net)

Comment: In order to fulfill your requirements, you need to be sound in PHP then ;)